# Getting a key of Nested Dic using multiple values criteria

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have the following Nested Dictionary:

```
go._Order_Data_DB.items()

Out[62]: dict_items([(84852344, {'_action': 'OPEN', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'EURUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 0}), (84852345, {'_action': 'CLOSE', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'EURUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 84852345}), 
(84852374, {'_action': 'OPEN', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'GBPUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 84852345})])
```

I would like to retrieve the Order Numbers (key) if two conditions are met: `'_action' == 'OPEN'` and `'_symbol' == ccy`. I tried using the function below but it only looks at the first criteria, would be great if someone knows how to make both criteria work, as it seems to be ignoring the 'and'.

```
def get_order_num(ccy): 
    for k, v in go._Order_Data_DB.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if v1 == ccy and v1 == 'OPEN':
                return(k)
```

Comment: small indentation problem when i published the question the 2nd line is indeed 4 spaces ahead of the 1st line

Comment: I think i found a solution below but still dont quite understand why the and function is not working this case if someone could elaborate? I literally spent a full day looking at syntax variations and nothing worked

Comment: def get_order_num(ccy): 
    for k, v in go._Order_Data_DB.items():
        for k1, v1 in v.items():
            if (v1 == ccy):
               for k1, v1 in v.items(): 
                   if v1 == 'OPEN':
                       return(k)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two main issues:

1. You don't need a nested loop to check specific keys in your sub-dictionaries. Your `if` statement can query keys from the values of your outer dictionary.
2. If multiple sub-dictionaries satisfy your criteria, only the first will be captured by `return`. To extract *all* items satisfying your conditions, `yield` results instead and then exhaust your generator via `list`.

Here's a demonstration;

```
d = dict([(84852344, {'_action': 'OPEN', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'EURUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 0}),
          (84852345, {'_action': 'CLOSE', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'EURUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 84852345}), 
          (84852374, {'_action': 'OPEN', '_type': 0, '_symbol': 'GBPUSD', '_price': 0.0, '_SL': 50, '_TP': 50, '_comment': 'DWX_Python_to_MT', '_lots': 0.01, '_magic': 123456, '_ticket': 84852345})])

def get_order_num(ccy): 
    for k, v in d.items():
        if v['_symbol'] == ccy and v['_action'] == 'OPEN':
            yield k

res1 = list(get_order_num('EURUSD'))  # [84852344]
res2 = list(get_order_num('GBPUSD'))  # [84852374]
```

Comment: Thanks jpp your solution does work, I hadnt heard about yield and the logic that return will just stay with the first instance it finds, highly appreciate you sharing the knowledge